# how can I generate QR code with logo in ionic

Tags: ionic3

How can i generate QR code with logo in ionic 3.

**my project configuration**

- Ionic Framework: 3.9.9
- Ionic App Scripts: 3.2.4
- Angular Core: 5.2.11
- Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.11
- Node: 14.17.3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from
[github](https://github.com/ushelp/EasyQRCodeJS#choose-what-you-need)

> check: Angular Support